How to produce a field obeying an imposed variogram?
I know that it is possible to construct a variogram from a given 2D field of data. However, what I would like to do is construct a 2D field of data that has a given mean and variance and obeys a specific variogram: a spherical model with a specified sill, range, and nugget. Is there any way to do this in python? Or R? (note: I am not familiar with R, I just know it's a statistics-friendly software)
I have done some reading online about various available functions, such as np.random.normal(), but these do not seem to do what I am looking for.
Any assistance with this would be much appreciated!
